Powerautomate flow: SharePoint list group by index and send to approver
I am trying to create a automated work flow for my SharePoint list such that the flow groups the index column and send to 1 manager for approval. The approval email should group the dollar value together as a whole.
For example the list below is the sharepoint list:



Index
Item
Value
Manager




1
1
10
A


1
2
15
A


1
3
12
A


2
1
5
B


2
2
11
B


2
3
15
B


3
1
18
C


3
2
15
C



This should trigger 1 email to Manager A to approve the expense of $37.Similar for manager B and C.

Use the advanced data operations connector and the Aggregate operation if you want to cut down your workflow … https://statesolutions.com.au/aggregate/
